How to find the gitlab reply-by-email address programmatically?
I'm building a web application which shows all the issues and notes from a project using the gitlab api.
I want to add a mailto link to create a new comment on an issue.
As far as i know there are two ways to do that:

replying to a notification from the Gitlab Support Bot (creates a incoming+%{key}@incoming.gitlab.com)

copying the issue-email-adress directly from the gitlab ui (creates a incoming+<project_namespace>-<project_path>-<project_id>-<incoming_mail_token>-issue-<issue_iid>@incoming.gitlab.com)


Is there any way to get either the %{key} or the incoming_mail_token (from the Gitlab Support Bot) programmatically? And if not is there any other way i could solve this problem?
I tried using incoming+<project_namespace>-<project_path>-<project_id>-issue<issue_iid>@incoming.gitlab.com, which does not work.
And i tried to find out how the key value is created but found nothing so far.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
